# How to download the files using vbscript in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am working on Classic Asp with VBScript. I am trying to display list of files from a directory with download option. like,[image]

When i click on the download link the corresponding file need to be download for that i have used the following code like,

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My First ASP Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjOutFile
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile

'Creating File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Getting the Folder Object
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("F:\karthik")

'Creating an Output File to write the File Names
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("F:\WindowsFiles.txt")

'Getting the list of Files
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Writing Name and Path of each File to Output File
Response.Write("<table cellpadding=""4"" cellspacing=""5"" >")
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    Response.Write("<tr><td>"&ObjFile.Name & String(50 - Len(ObjFile.Name), " ")&"</td><td><a href=""#"" language=""VBScript"" onclick=""vbscript:HTTPDownload('"&ObjFile.Path&"','C:\Users\stellent\Downloads\')"">Download</a></td></tr>")
Next
 Response.Write("</table>")
ObjOutFile.Close
%><br>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub HTTPDownload( myURL, myPath )
    ' Standard housekeeping
    Dim i, objFile, objFSO, objHTTP, strFile, strMsg
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

    ' Create a File System Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

    ' Check if the specified target file or folder exists,
    ' and build the fully qualified path of the target file
    If objFSO.FolderExists( myPath ) Then
        strFile = objFSO.BuildPath( myPath, Mid( myURL, InStrRev( myURL, "/" ) + 1 ) )
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists( Left( myPath, InStrRev( myPath, "\" ) - 1 ) ) Then
        strFile = myPath
    Else
        WScript.Echo "ERROR: Target folder not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create or open the target file
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFile, ForWriting, True )

    ' Create an HTTP object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )

    ' Download the specified URL
    objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    objHTTP.Send

    ' Write the downloaded byte stream to the target file
    For i = 1 To LenB( objHTTP.ResponseBody )
        objFile.Write Chr( AscB( MidB( objHTTP.ResponseBody, i, 1 ) ) )
    Next

    ' Close the target file
    objFile.Close( )
End Sub
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .. and what happens ? is the download happening ?

Comment: Yes.. No download happenning. I think my anchor tag doesnt call vbscript method.

Comment: this is an asp file, not vbs. you will have to put the code in the script block in asp tags and try. the link will have to do a postback and call the function to download

Comment: Ok. could you please tell how to call the method from anchor tag click event since i am a newbie to asp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are trying to do this on the server-side using client-side scripting. Here is a better solution that uses server-side ASP to send the file. You will need to split your code over two pages.

Your current script should be replaced with this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title> My First ASP Page </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<% Dim fso 
Dim ObjFolder 
Dim ObjOutFile 
Dim ObjFiles 
Dim ObjFile 

'Creating File System Object 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

'Getting the Folder Object 
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("F:\karthik") 

'Getting the list of Files 
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files 

'Writing Name and Path of each File to Output File 
Response.Write("<table cellpadding=""4"" cellspacing=""5"" >") 
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles 
    Response.Write("<tr><td>"&ObjFile.Name & String(50 - Len(ObjFile.Name), " ")&"</td><td><a href=""download.asp?file=" & Server.UrlEncode(ObjFile.Name) & """>Download</a></td></tr>") 
Next 
 Response.Write("</table>") 
%><br> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Then you need to create another script which I have called **download.asp** which handles the download:

```
<%
Dim objConn, strFile
Dim intCampaignRecipientID

strFile = Request.QueryString("file")

If strFile <> "" Then

    Response.Buffer = False
    Dim objStream
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile("F:\karthik\" & strFile)
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown"
    Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFile
    Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing

End If
%>
```

Comment: Thanks John, i was stuck in a similar situation but its fixed NOW!!

Comment: Be careful with this method. There's nothing stopping the user from supplying their own filename in the querystring and having your script download it for them. Watch out for parent path requests: `..\..\global.asa`, for example.

Comment: Good advice @Bond - should at least reject any requests where `file` contains a backslash.

Comment: `objConn` and `intCampaignRecipientID` are not used. :)

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution, but users can see the downloads in the history, or modify the querystring. This solution can be modified for POST usage this way: 
    in the page code modify the link:

    `` <a href="#" onclick="getfile(this);">FileName</a>` ``

and further down

```
    <form id="frm2dl" action="download.asp" method="post"><input type="hidden" id="file2dl" name="file2dl" value="" /></form>
```

then in your javascript file get the filename:

```
    function getfile(obj) {
      var f=obj.innerText;
      $("#frm2dl #file2dl").val(f);
      $("#frm2dl").submit();
    }
```

alternately you could use a file ID then in the download.asp have a lookup function from ID to filename. 
Then in the download.asp use `request.form("file2dl")` instead of request.querystring.

UPDATE:
Also, depending on server version you might get the 4MB limit (I have to work with Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on intranet). Therefore for large files the code will not work. Here is my improved version:

```
Dim strFileName, strFilePath, objFSO, objStream, objFile, intFileSize
Const lChkSize = 524288 ' 500KB - server typical limit is 4MB 
'If session("loggedIn") = True Then ' insert your logon validation code here. bypassed for testing
    strFileName = request.form("file2dl")
    strFilename = Replace(strFilename,"..","") ' prevent parent path navigation - also ensure uploaded files do not contain this sequence
    strFilename = Replace(strFilename,"/","") ' prevent path navigation
    strFilename = Replace(strFilename,"\","") ' filenames should already be cleaned by a previous process
    strFilePath = server.MapPath("/insert your URL absolute sources filepath here/" & strFilename)
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFilePath)
        intFileSize = objFile.Size
        Set objFile = Nothing
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & strFileName
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-msdownload"
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", intFileSize
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        objStream.Open
        objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath
        Do While Not objStream.EOS And Response.IsClientConnected
            Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read(lChkSize)
            Response.Flush()
        Loop
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
    Else
        Response.write "Error finding file: " & request.form("file2dl")
    End if
    Set objFSO = Nothing
'End If
```