# PDF protection and SEO in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, seo

I have a classic asp website where I am selling pdfs. Ocne user pays, I give them a link to download the pdf like this:

https://mysite.com/products/ebook/mypdf.pdf

I want to protect it from 
(1) the search engines indexing 
(2) people accessing it directly without buying it.

How can I do it?

Please suggest

Comment: the pdf's shouldn't be accessible directly but have to be streamed so you can check in code first if they have permission to download.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an extra ASP page, e.g. getpdf.asp to download the content.

See this answer, this covers most of what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946733/911635

You will have to add some access control to check if the current user has access to the file.