# ASP Classic download file script

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a website being built in ASP Classic, and am having some trouble with a script that allows a user to download a file, but hides the path to the file.

When a user is on a page, they will see a link. The link is coded like this:

```
<a href="download.asp?file=FILE-NAME-HERE" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

This link takes them to download.asp where code is run to get the file and deliver it. Here is the code I have right now:

```
<%
const adTypeBinary = 1
dim strFilePath, strFile

strFilePath = "/_uploads/private/" 
strFile = Request.QueryString("file") 

if strFile <> "" then
    'Set the content type to the specific type that you are sending.
     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
     Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFile

     set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     objStream.open
     objStream.type = adTypeBinary
     objStream.LoadFromFile(strFilePath & strFile)

    response.binarywrite objStream.Read

    objStream.close
    Set objStream = nothing

end if
%>
```

This code I put together from both questions on this site ([How to download the files using vbscript in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929866/how-to-download-the-files-using-vbscript-in-classic-asp)), and from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276488

What is happening, however, is that the download.asp page is giving me a "file not found" error, even though the file is correctly in the web directory "/_uploads/private/".

The file type could be one of several, including pdf, xls, docx, etc.

Is there something in my code that is not allowing the file to be found?

Comment: Does IIS have read permissions for that folder?

Comment: Yes, the current permissions values for the "/_uploads/private/" folder are 755.

Comment: Try the whole drive letter + path.

Comment: You could try using [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) to resolve the path, ie `objStream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath(strFilePath & strFile))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to user oracle certified professional, in the comments above.

What worked was adding "Server.MapPath" to resolve the file location.

Instead of using:

```
objStream.LoadFromFile(strFilePath & strFile)
```

I changed it to:

```
objStream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath(strFilePath & strFile))
```

Now the link triggers the file to properly download.