# Displaying a PDF with ADODB.Stream

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working on replacing a system that primarily uses PDF files to give users their monthly reports.

The problem I'm having is being able to prevent one user from seeing another's information. For example if user1 has a file at www.mysite.com/user1/file.pdf they could edit the URL to www.mysite.com/user2/file.pdf and see the files of user2.

The way I've been trying to get around this is to disable anonymous access (it's an IIS server) to the user folders so it's impossible to get direct access to files and have view_file.asp bring in the file using ADODB.Stream. I'm having a problem though that some users have not been able to view the files. It seems to only be people using IE but it's hard to be sure.

I basically just need to either fix this to work in all browser/configs or find an alternative way to display the file through the browser.

```
Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adoStream.Type = 1
adoStream.Open()

adoStream.LoadFromFile "C:/path-to-file/" & curUser & curDir

Response.Buffer = true
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Do While Not adoStream.eos
    Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(1024 * 8)
    Response.Flush
Loop
Response.End()
adoStream.close
Set adoStream=nothing
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP Classic download file script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777488/asp-classic-download-file-script)

Comment: could you show the code from view_file.asp? furthermore when you disable anonymous access, you probably do note need that view_file.asp?

Comment: you are flushing the Response although the stream is not at its end furthermore you are closing the stream after Response.end this code is never reached.

Comment: I've edited the post to show view_file.asp. I believe if the system was setup using windows authentication you would be right but the system has a database for the login system. The only thing we're disabling anonymous access on is the data files for the users.

Comment: I removed the Response.Flush as well as the adoStream.close. I thought this was working but I just got 3 calls this morning that people were not able to access the files. It appears to only be happening on certain Windows XP systems, so far no reports of errors with any other operating systems.

Comment: Is there any solution to do the same thing but using VBA instead? I can't find any solution..