# Download and save a webpage using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, save, download

I am trying to give users the option to download and save a webpage to where ever they want. I have been looking all over for a solution but nothing seems to be working. I am using vbscript in classic asp.

This is what I tried last

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "" &Session("ServerURL") & "/idautomation/IDAutomationStreamingLinear.aspx?D=MAPS$"&request.QueryString("catcode")&"%25"&request.QueryString("typecode")&"&X=0.09&BH=3&S=0&CC=T&LM=5&TM=7.5&ST=F", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "d:\DownloladPdf.pdf", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

but its throwing a "Write to file failed. " on the .savetofile line.

I want the user to be able to chose where to save it to...

Comment: Show code which you have tried. This is not homework solving service

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download the files using vbscript in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929866/how-to-download-the-files-using-vbscript-in-classic-asp)

Comment: The above link has an answer that has an example of how to do it with a stream as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save to the users computer from server side code VBscript directly as this would be a major security issue allowing drive by compromises of people browsing a web page.  The reason possibly that it is throwing an error is that it is trying to save it server side, but there is no D: on the server.

Instead you want to serve the PDF to the browser using Response and let the browser display or save the PDF.

The below example is using a bytes array rather than a stream, but it should be similar.  If you want to force it to download rather than show in the browser, change the content-disposition to attachment.  You can also change the filename to whatever you like.

```
if Len(pdfBytes) > 0 then
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.AddHeader "Cache-Control", "public, max-age=1" ' Setting Cache-Control to max-age=1 rather than no-cache due to IE8 bug
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","inline; filename=filename.pdf"
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Expires = 0
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)
    Response.Flush
    Response.End
    Response.Close
end if
```