# Download files using classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I followed the below link but I am not able to download the file :

[StackOverflow Question on same Topic from where I used the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929866/how-to-download-the-files-using-vbscript-in-classic-asp)

Here is my download.asp code :

```
<%
  Dim objConn, strFile
  Dim intCampaignRecipientID

  strFile = Request.QueryString("file")

  If strFile <> "" Then

Response.Buffer = False
Dim objStream
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
'FilePath=server.MapPath("some_folder/DOWNLOAD/")
'Response.Write(Server.MapPath("some_folder/download/") & "\" & strFile)
objStream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("some_folder/download/") & "\" & 
strFile)
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown"
Response.Addheader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFile
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing

 End If
 %>
```

I am getting Error Invalid Response...The page is not accessible error.

The download folder is at the same level as wwwroot folder so the folder structure is :

wwwroot              some_folder/download

I have my download folder in wwwroot/download.asp that is why I am using server.mappath. I even tried ../some_folder/download but same error.

Can someone help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try making sure the file exists and is accessible? if you put the following into the browser url address bar, what happens?   http://www.yourDomain.com/some_folder/download/fileName.ext

Comment: also, make sure you have the right permissions on the folder that contains the file(s). At the bare minimum, you should have the IUSR account accessible to the folder.

Comment: You would find it much easier to debug if you configure your IIS to send detailed error messages to the browser - that will tell you exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery I navigated to  yourDomain.com/some_folder/download/fileName.ext it showed a blank page but in the network tab of chrome's developer toolbar I see my file as being transfered with a status of 304.

Comment: @TimWilliams I enabled debugging but still getting the same error. No debugging info is getting printed on the screen

Comment: In IIS the home directory is set to E:\wwwroot but the diretory some_folder is in E:\some_folder not in E:\wwwroot\some_folder. There are some pages  that are writing files to this E:\some_folder and it's working. Any ideas as to why I am getting this ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. I am able to display all the files with a download button next to it. But when I click on download error.

Comment: I even tried this objStream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("some_folder/download/" &  strFile)) I outputted the Server.MapPath("sau_load/download/" &  strFile) and got E:\some_folder\download\file.ext. But still error.

Comment: Hi I added Response.Charset = “UTF-8” and changed content type to text/plain. It is downloading now. But 0 bytes files is not downloading. Please advise.

Comment: Hi - I took your code and plugged it into my site, changing only the folder it is reading from. All worked fine for a test case using a readme.txt file with content. If I make the file zero characters then chrome gives a ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE message and says that the site cannot be reached.

Comment: Hi - I did not get ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE but the loading just kept spinning. So I only display files whose size is greater than zero.